# Convertir resultado de consulta a string para una vista laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

En un modelo tengo un método con una consulta SQL para obtener la suma total de los conceptos de una reparación.

Este es el método:

```
public function totalCon() {
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(quantity*amount) FROM concepts WHERE repair_id = $this->repair_id";
    $totalCon = DB::select($sql);
    
    return $totalCon;
}
```

Ese resultado lo tengo que mostrar en una vista, pero cuando llamo al método en la vista blade me da el siguiente error:

**htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

Lo que yo devuelvo en el método es un array con un objeto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la vista blade necesito que sea un string y no un array con un objeto.

Cómo convierto ese array con objeto a string? Sólo necesito mostrar el resultado del float (3865)

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te devuelve un arreglo, asi que lo mas conveniente es que le pongas un alias a tu SUM y lo devuelvas tal cual.

```
public function totalCon() {
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(quantity*amount) as total FROM concepts WHERE repair_id = $this->repair_id";
    $totalCon = DB::select($sql);
    
    return $totalCon[0]->total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes diferentes formas de hacerlo:

```
number_format($float,0,'.','');
$string = sprintf("%.3f", $float);
```